# Chain ID of Remix Javascript VM

Tags: remix, multisignature

I am attempting to test out a simplemultisig contract (https://github.com/christianlundkvist/simple-multisig) but it requires the chain id. I have been testing using ganache but wanted to switch to remix to make it a bit easier.

Any idea on how to get the chain id of the vm and does it change every time you reload the page?

Answer (score 0):

You check it by using `block.chainid` which seems to be available on the global scope. Use [hardhat/console](https://hardhat.org/guides/hardhat-console.html) to see it - I got value **1**.